# jquery: getting any change event on any form

Tags: jquery, forms

I know I can get any change event on one form by using this code:

```
$("#testForm :input").change(function() {
console.log($(this).attr('name'));      
});
```

How would I get it if I have multiple forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either do something like that which will get all changes to all form inputs, or give each separate form an ID.

```
$("form :input").change(function() {
console.log($(this).attr('name'));      
});
```

Comment: This is also to the other respondents - I tried form (should have mentioned that, doh) and it didn't work. Let me run it again and see.

Comment: Sigh, now it works. The universe and I will be having words...sorry I can't accept all three answers...thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("form :input").change(function() {
console.log($(this).attr('name'));      
});
```

for all forms, but if you still want only that one form

```
$("#testForm :input").change(function() {
console.log($(this).attr('name'));      
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with tag selector

```
$("form :input").change(function() {
   console.log($(this).attr('name'));      
});
```